# PROCEDURE test_multi_sets in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

can someone explain me what does this chunk of code means?

```
DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_multi_sets`()
    DETERMINISTIC
begin
        select user() as first_col;
        select user() as first_col, now() as second_col;
        select user() as first_col, now() as second_col, now() as third_col;
        end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Because my database exports only with this, and it seems to cause troubles for me to import it to another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
DEFINER=`username`@`localhost`
```

tells MySQL that the procedure is executed with the rights that the user `username@localhost` has. If it causes problems to import, you most likely haven't created that user on the destination server yet.

The procedure is just a test someone wrote. It does nothing important, it simply selects the current user and the current time.

I bet you can delete it.

Comment: @KazikJarmolovski Any more questions about this? Any feedback?